# HP UX server , make_recovery vs make_tape_recovery

Tags: backup, hp, hp-ux

I have to do a backup on different HP servers with different operation systems (hpux 10.20, hpux 11.00 and hpux 11.11).

I found information about make_recovery and make_tape_recovery, but I don't know the difference between the two commands.

What is the difference betwen make_recovery vs make_tape_recovery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to hp-ux documentation;

`make_recovery(103): The make_recovery command will be replaced by make_tape_recovery. Both commands are supported in this release (Ignite-UX Revision 3.2). Please read the man page make_tape_recovery(1M) for usage of the new command. In a future release, make_recovery will be replaced by a script that calls make_tape_recovery`